# Unexpected closing tag "span". It may happen when the tag has already been closed by another tag. Error in the template of component HomeComponent

Tags: html, angular

I have downloaded a source code from Github. There is an error in home.component.html file. The error is associated with span element. The code is below:

```
<div class="product-info">
              <h2 class="product-title h5 mb-0"><a href="#">Sleeve linen shirt</a></h2>
              <span class="price">
                  <del>60<pre wp-pre-tag-5=""></pre>lt;/del>
                  $50.10
              </span>
          </div>
```

Someone, please let me know the fix here. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your close tag for  has `lt;` instead of `<`

```
<div class="product-info">
              <h2 class="product-title h5 mb-0"><a href="#">Sleeve linen shirt</a></h2>
              <span class="price">
                  <del>60<pre wp-pre-tag-5=""></pre></del> <!-- right here -->
                  $50.10
              </span>
          </div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. That was a quick response. Thank you so much!

Comment: NP, if this fixes your problem don't forget to accept/upvote

Comment: I tried to upvote, but it wouldn't let me as I am a new contributor. It says that I need at least 15 reputations to do so. I will definitely upvote your answer once I get there.

Comment: @StylishBros you can still accept the answer then.

Comment: It says that I have to wait 2 minutes. Edit: I did!

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing tag for 'del'

```html
<div class="product-info">
    <h2 class="product-title h5 mb-0"><a href="#">Sleeve linen shirt</a></h2>
    <span class="price">
        <del>60<pre wp-pre-tag-5=""></pre></del>
        $50.10
    </span>
</div>
```